# Garbage collection, camera and video object

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

How do I clean up after I've finished using the Camera object and Video Object?

Do I just write:

```
_cameraInstance = null;
_videoInstance = null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to remove any event listeners you have associated with your camera and video objects and detach camera from video with _videoInstance.attachCamera(null) .